# Locker App Method

Tags: java, arrays

This is a lockers app I'm building that ensures that lockers are placed so that customers in the city are always within a short distance from the a locker in the ciry.  To account for this, I need a way to model locker placements and distances from lockers.

For this I am provide the following:

1. A positive whole number range 1-9 representing the length of your city in city blocks
2. A positive whole number range 1-9 representing the width of your city in city blocks
3. An array containing all X coordinates representing Locker Locations, each X coordinate range 1-9.
4. An array containing all Y coordinates representing Locker Locations, each Y coordinate range 1-9.

The job here is to contruct a 2D grid of the city.  Each element of the grid should be a positive whole number that specifies the number of blocks to the closet locker.  The distance the between two blocks is the sum of their horizontal and vertical distance(a move in the diagonal direction is therefore considered a distance of 2).  Return your grid as 2D array of integers where the first index corresponds to the X dimension and the second index corresponsds to the Y direction.

Example #1:

Given:

1. 3
2. 5
3. [1]
4. [1]

Return:

```
012
123
234
345
456
```

Example #2:

Given:

1. 5
2. 7
3. [2,4]
4. [3,7]

Return:

```
32345
21234
10123
21234
32323
43212
32101
```

This is the method I was aske to use:

static int[][] getLockerDistanceGrid(int cityLength, int cityWidth, int[] lockerXCoordinates, int[] lockerYCoordinates) {
    }

How would I do this?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is an awfully broad question... At least show us what you've done.

Comment: A good start would be to iterate through all the locations (two stacked for loops would do the trick nicely) and then at each location, figure out where the closest locker is by comparing your location to the locations given in the lists (this should be doable with some very simple arithmetic).

Comment: I havn't done any code yet.  I wasn't sure how to get started.

Comment: You can start the method by declaring the array you'll need for the output table: `array = new int[cityWidth][]; for(int i=0; i < cityWidth; ++i ) { array[i] = new int[cityLength]; }` Or you can code it swapping hte Width and Length.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a bit modified BFS

```
private static class Node {
    public Node (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int x, y;
}

static int[][] getLockerDistanceGridBfs(int cityLength, int cityWidth, int[] lockerXCoordinates, int[] lockerYCoordinates) {
    if (lockerXCoordinates == null || lockerYCoordinates == null || lockerXCoordinates.length != lockerYCoordinates.length)
        return null;

    int[][] city = new int[cityWidth][cityLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < city[0].length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < city.length; j++)
            city[j][i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    Queue<Node> nodesToDo = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lockerXCoordinates.length; i++) {
        city[lockerXCoordinates[i] - 1][lockerYCoordinates[i] - 1] = 0;
        nodesToDo.add(new Node(lockerXCoordinates[i] - 1, lockerYCoordinates[i] - 1));
    }

    while(!nodesToDo.isEmpty()) {
        Node v = nodesToDo.poll();
        int newDist = city[v.x][v.y] + 1;
        List<Node> neighbours = getNeighbours(cityLength, cityWidth, v.x, v.y);
        for(Node node : neighbours) {
            if(newDist < city[node.x][node.y]) {
                city[node.x][node.y] = newDist;
                nodesToDo.add(node);
            }
        }
    }

    return city;
}

private static List<Node> getNeighbours(int cityLength, int cityWidth, int x, int y) {
    List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>(4);
    if(x - 1 >= 0) {
        result.add(new Node(x - 1, y));
    }
    if(y - 1 >= 0) {
        result.add(new Node(x, y - 1));
    }
    if(x + 1 < cityWidth) {
        result.add(new Node(x + 1, y));
    }
    if(y + 1 < cityLength) {
        result.add(new Node(x, y + 1));
    }

    return result;
}
```